# How to iterate through list of variables when name of each ends with an integer/number?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var activeThing_1
var activeThing_2
var activeThing_3
etc
```

Wanna go through each of these and forcefully set boolean value. How would it look in C#?

Comment: Use an array or `List` instead of creating a bunch of variables

Comment: You can't do that without using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array.

```
bool[] active_Thing;
for(int i=0;i<arraysize;i++)
    active_thing[i]=boolvalue;
```

Comment: Do I really need array? I know that there is only X such variables and I do not fetch them automatically, can I just:  

    `for(int i=1;i<X;i++)   
    this.active_thing[i]=boolvalue;`

Comment: @Digika that's the whole point of an array is to group similar variables like these together so you can iterate them.

Comment: Yeah, that's not gonna work for me, I'm requesting public variable from another script (Unity3D) through instance. Oh well, thanks for the hits anyway

Comment: why not get the values from the other script and then put them into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<string, bool> dict`

Where the string is the name of your setting.

`dict.Add("activeThing_1", true)` can be accessed via `dict["activeThing_1"]`